# Setting a React JS State via a Parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I am wondering if it is possible to create a function that takes in a parameter (either a string of the state name or the actual state) then set the state of the state relating to the parameter.

```
SetState(x) {
        // Assume x can be any state we have already declared (I need it work for multiple states)
        this.setState((x): false);
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a few examples of how you'd call this function? It sounds like `setState` already does what you want...

Comment: yes you can do that with parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You put the param in square brackets to create a dynamic key:

```
doSetState(str) {
  this.setState({ [str]: false });
}
```